# Ruby metaprogramming question

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

When I call `self.class.instance_variable_set("@var", ...)` from inside a class method, where is that variable actually stored? Is it on the class itself? On the instance of that class? I can't seem to find it with any of the following:

```
e = Example.new
e.instance_variables
e.class.class_variables
```

I even tried using the `(class << self; self; end)` trick but I can't find anything (http://ruby-metaprogramming.rubylearning.com/html/seeingMetaclassesClearly.html).

Here is the code snippet (which works as I need) but I'm not sure *why* it works :)

```
module HandyModule
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end
  module ClassMethods
    def use_template(template_name)
      self.class.instance_variable_set("@_template", template_name)
    end
    def build(attributes = {})
      template_name = self.class.instance_variable_get("@_template")
      # do stuff with the template
    end
  end
end

class Example
  include HandyModule
  use_template :contact_form
end
```

Essentially I can include this handy module, and then I have a class method called `use_template` with which I can specify which template to be used by my build method.

Comment: Don't forget that classes are objects. They're merely objects that have a `class` of `Class`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `use_template` inside the class definition, the `self` is the class `Example`. When you call `self.class`, it is `Example.class`, or `Class`. You define the instance variable to the class of the classes.

```
class Class
  p @_template
end
# prints :contact_form
```

You probably should use just `self` instead of `self.class`.

Comment: Brilliant, that makes sense now. I must just remember, it's all about the context of the `self`